# jsp - Combining include file and jsp methods

Tags: file, jsp, include

I'm trying to run a jsp method on an included file. How would I do that?

I have my included file:

```
<%@ include file="/foobar/Foo.bar" %>
```

And I have my `foo(String str)` method.

Now the question is, how would I call `foo()` on the file `/foobar/Foo.bar`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the include file I created a method:

```
public String readResource(String resource){
        try{
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(resource)));
        String line = null;

        String data = "";
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if(data!="")data+="\n";
            data+=line;
        }
        return data;
        }catch(IOException e){
            return "";
        }
    }
```

And then I used `<%=foo(readResource("/foobar/Foo.bar"))%>`.